# GET http://localhost:5000/data 404 (NOT FOUND)

Tags: python, flask, import

i have created a form for user input, and run it in app.py with flask. What i want to achieve is to be able to get the user data, and then save it to my mongodb database. This is my html for the form.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/Recording.css">
    </head>
    
    <div class="header">
        <h1>Create a recording</h1>
    </div>

<body>
    <div class="create">
    <form name="formdata">
        <label for="trolley">Trolley</label>
        <input type="text" id=trolley name="trolley" size="180" required>

        <label for="datetime">Date & time</label><br>
        <input type="datetime-local" id="datetime" name="datetime"><br required>

        <label for="temp">Temperature</label>
        <input type="text" id="temp" name="temp" size="180" required>

        <input id="button1" type="submit" value="Record"">
    </form>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/papaparse@5.2.0/papaparse.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../static/Recording.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../static/database.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my app.py file

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, jsonify, json, request
from flask_pymongo import PyMongo
from pymongo import MongoClient

app = Flask(__name__)

#routes
from q2 import subroutes

client =  MongoClient("mongodb+srv://Stanislas:reddevils97@tma.p1mbs.mongodb.net/<dbname>?retryWrites=true&w=majority")
db = client.get_database("smarttrolley")
records = db.recordings

@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template('SmartTrolley.html')

@app.route("/userinput/")
def userInput():
    return render_template('Recording.html')

if __name__=='__main__':
    app.debug = True
    app.run(port=5000)
'''
```

this is my subroutes.py file, which handles the user data and post it in the route "/data"

```
from flask import Flask
from app import app
from q2.models import User

@app.route("/data", methods=["POST"])
def data():
    return User().input()
```

This is my models.py file, which collects the data from the "/data" route, which then proceeds to insert the data into my mongoDB database.

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from app import db, records

class User:

    def input(self):
        inputs = {
            "_id": "",
            "trolleyname": request.form.get('trolley'),
            "Date & Time": request.form.get('datetime'),
            "Temperature": request.form.get('temp')
        } 

        db.records.insert_one(inputs)

        return jsonify(inputs), 200
```

I am using jquery ajax call for the data to be sent. I am able to receive the data via the console.log everytime the user submits data, and everything is working fine. However, i am receiving the error "GET http://localhost:5000/data 404 (NOT FOUND)", which shows that they can't locate my "/data" route. Is anyone able to help me and find out whats wrong, because i have done the importing of the subroutes into my app.py and nothing seems to be working. thank you

Comment: Your `/data` route is only allowed with the POST method. Not GET

Answer (score 0):

It is only allowed for POST method in your code

```
@app.route("/data", methods=["POST"])
def data():
   return User().input()
```

#You are using GET method here

GET http://localhost:5000/data 404 (NOT FOUND)

## Either change above code to following:

```
@app.route("/data", methods=["GET"])
def data():
    return User().input()
```

#Or you can hit POST request